# Efficiently combine many Document Term Matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, tm, large-data

If I have a list of many document term matrices I can do this to combine them:

```
# setup for example
require(tm)
data("acq")
data("crude")
acq_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(acq)
crude_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)
# make list of dtms
list_of_dtms <- list(acq_dtm, crude_dtm)
# convert list of dtms into one big dtm
dtms_combined_into_one <- do.call(tm:::c.DocumentTermMatrix, list_of_dtms)
```

But this seems very slow and memory intensive, and is a major bottleneck when dealing with a few thousand dtms. How can I combine them faster and using less memory?

Since the dtm is a sparse matrix, I wonder if anyone knows of a method for combining sparse matrices that might be useful here. I'm my actual use-case I am not starting with a corpus but lists of word counts.

Here's an rfiddle, in case that's useful for quick testing: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=SojC9ZlA (seems promising, but I haven't found it very reliable, is there anything good for this kind of quick prototyping, that can install packages?)

Comment: A document term matrix is a SLAM simple triplet matrix, which means its just a set of triples (i, j, value). If you knew the terms were the same across all the corpora and that i,j represented the same value in each dtm, you could just bind them together. But that usually won't be true. What about combining all the corpora together  into one big corpus and then computing the dtm? Seems like that might be faster.

Comment: Thanks, can you expand in an answer?

Comment: Well, I did some testing and my idea of rebuilding the dtm from the combined corpora was an order of magnitude slower than what you're already doing. I'll post what I was thinking with the sparse matrices.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a trivial way to speed up what you are already doing (maybe there is a clever way). Take a look at `str(acq_dtm)`:

```
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:4135] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ j       : int [1:4135] 20 33 60 135 187 206 238 256 268 286 ...
 $ v       : num [1:4135] 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 6 1 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 50
 $ ncol    : int 2103
 $ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:50] "10" "12" "44" "45" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:2103] "0.5165" "0.523" "0.8" "100" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
 - attr(*, "Weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```

`i` points to a document number in the Docs component, and `j` points to a term (the first few terms are numbers). `v` is the frequency of term `j` in document `i`. When you do

```
c(acq_dtm, crude_dtm)
```

it's more than just stacking up some sparse matrices (that can be done with  `slam::abind_simple_sparse_array`); the `v` components of the two matrices have to be unioned and then the appropriate `i` and `j` values have to be recomputed.

If I were going to research this more I might have a look at the documentation for `slam`.

Also the code for `tm:::c.TermDocumentMatrix` shows how tm is doing this calculation; don't know if it's possible to improve it.